# Accurate number on .height

Tags: jquery, css, html, resize

I made a div with width 100% and height width*.1 in jquery.

I managed to expand the height dispite the ratio but I can't manage to expand it accuratly.

I actually would like to expand it to 400px, is it possible ?

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/3/

```
* 
{
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
border:0
}

.container
{
    width:100%;
    background:black;

}

<figure class="container">
</figure>

$('.container').height($(this).width()*0.1);
  var toggleCheck =0;
$('.container').click(function(){

    if(toggleCheck ==1){
         $(this).stop().animate({height: ( $(this).height()-$(this).width()*0.1 )});
        toggleCheck = 0;
    }else{
 $(this).stop().animate({height: ($(this).width()*0.1 + $(this).height())});
        toggleCheck = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand: if you want to expand to 400px, why bothering taking the calculation? Possibly I didn't understand your issue?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/6/) what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/7/)**</kbd>

```
var $cont = $('.container'),
    init_size = $cont.width() * 0.1,
    c = 0,                // counter
    s = [400,init_size];  // sizes array

$cont.height( init_size );

$cont.click(function(){   
  $(this).stop().animate({ height: s[c++%2] });
});
```

Comment: Nice, good demo of using `animate`.  For the non-math types, please explain `c++%2` to alternate height values.

Comment: `c++` post-increments `c` (returns the original value, then increments). `% 2` takes that value and limits it to the values `0` and `1`. That value is used as the index to be accessed from array `s`. The returned value from `s` is assigned to `height`. All in one fell swoop. `%` is called the [modulus (or remainder) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: @AaronBlenkush I wrote so many times about `%` and `++` in my answers that this time I just missed it :\ Thanks for explaining it

Comment: @roXon is there a way if I had a "content" div inside container to remove the ratio and to allow width resize ? Or maybe to keep the ratio but to make that content 4000px large so that it keeps the 400px height and can make both animate simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are just wanting to grow the container by 400px you can use the following js:

```
var container = $('.container');
container.height(container.width()*0.1);
var originalHeight = container.height();
var newHeight = 400 + originalHeight;

container.click(function(){
  if($(this).height() == originalHeight){
     $(this).stop().animate({height: newHeight});
  }else{
     $(this).stop().animate({height: originalHeight});
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/16/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).stop().animate({height: 400});
```